# OpenVPN and TomatoVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, tomato

Wondering if someone can help me with the following.

I have updated my Linksys router with TomatoVPN and used the following config:

```
Interface Type:TAP
Protocol:UDP
Port:1195
Firewall Custom
Authorization Mode:Static Key
```

I have then inserted the static key generated in OpenVPN saved and started the service.

connect.ovpn.

```
# Use the following to have your client computer send all traffic through your router
# (remote gateway)
remote (entered my DNS/DHCP servers external IP address here)
port 1195
dev tap
secret static.key.txt
proto udp
comp-lzo
route-gateway 192.168.1.1
redirect-gateway
float
```

I've then placed my static key in a file in the same directory as your connect.ovpn (static.key.txt)

Now OpenVPN is installed on a laptop that I use at home. I have plugged in the laptop to my home connection and started connect.ovpn

The Local Area Connection is connected as 'Home Network 3' - and when I start OpenVPN it is connected as 'Local Area Connection 2' and this is showing as 'Unidentified Network' and it appears there is no network access.

TAP-Win32 Adapter V9 appears to be the adaptors name and the IP and DNS properties are set to automatic. If I open up the OpenVPN GUI it shows an error message saying "Connecting to connect has failed". Looking at the error message behind this pop-up one line says "TCP/UDP Socket bind failed on local address [undef]:1195 Address already in use [WSAEADDRINUSE] Could anyone possibly help me further with this please?

Comment: The above was cut off...and this is the remainder:

Comment: Found this which may help...http://writeonly.wordpress.com/2009/06/16/tcpview-saves-the-day/ Will give that a try in the morning and see if anything is taking up 1195...would still like to hear any other thoughts/sugestions though.

Comment: Strange...everyone else seems to have set up OpenVPN/TomatoVPN on 1194 and yet I have it on 1195. Would it make any difference changing it over perhaps to port 1194 at the office?

Comment: What does running at the command prompt the following provides: **netstat -an | find "1195"** or **netstat -ano | find "1195"** Depends on the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help or not as I use OpenVPN (Server) on DD-WRT but on the OpenVPN Windows client-side I just could not connect until I added the following to the .ovpn file:

```
script-security 2 system
```

Then it just worked.

Don't know why that config option isn't front and center in the docs I read.

HTH